# Django - Sort a list by related fields

Tags: python, django, algorithm, django-models, django-views

My models:

```
Item:
    name
    desc

Type:
    name

Value:
    item.ForeignKey(Item)
    type.ForeignKey(Type)
    val.CharField # varchar or numeric
```

Now I have an objects list of items but not a QuerySet, for instance: `items = [<object:1>, <object:2>, <object:4>]`. And `t = 5` is an id of a row from Type.

I want to sort this list by `val` of table `Value` and type of value is `t`. Any idea?

Thanks alot!

**UPDATE:**
- I've added a new condition.

Comment: If you have a proper list, what's wrong with `list.sort()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use lambda function to sort the list of items (assuming there is a one to one relationship between `Item` and `Value` model, otherwise I don't think the question makes sense)

```
 items.sort(key=lambda object: object.value_set.all()[0].val)
```

Although the point to be noted is that the sorting will be in memory.

**For Updated Question**

Just adding a filter should do the task

```
 items.sort(key=lambda object: object.value_set.filter(type__id=5)[0].val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(items.objects.all(), key=lambda item: item.value_set.get().val if item.value_set.all() else None)
```

should do it in case your foreign key isn't set for some items.

Answer (score 1):

Check *Key Functions* in [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) sort tutorial that I found in python docs